# How to convert OutputStream to File?

Tags: android

The code below get image from some location - and make this image compress image. 
But i need to make the compress Image to be File ... How can i do it ?

```
   File compressFile = null;
   File file = new File("MyFile");
   OutputStream fOut    = new FileOutputStream(file);
   if(image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut))
   {
       fOut.flush();
       fOut.close();

      compressFile = ??? // I need here to make the OutputStream  to be back to file. 
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`image.compress` already writes the image to the file, assuming you gave a correct file name.
So use it like this:

```
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myimage.png");
   FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
   image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
   fOut.close();
```

Comment: What's the first line for?

Comment: It had no use, now I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation for `OutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html):

> Most clients will use output streams that write data to the file system (FileOutputStream), the network (getOutputStream()/getOutputStream()), or to an in-memory byte array (ByteArrayOutputStream).

Meaning the data sent to the `OutputStream` has allready been written to your `file`.

If what you mean is that you need access to the file once it has been compressed you should look at [documentation for the `compress()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) which states:

> If this returns true, the bitmap can be reconstructed by passing a corresponding inputstream to BitmapFactory.decodeStream().

So what you need to do is this:

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( new FileInputStream( file ) );
```