# Android - Compress Bitmap to upload to MySQL Database

Tags: android, bitmap

When I take a photo with the camera it should be compressed and uploaded to mysql db.

I checked the function Bitmap.compress() and the output is in a ByteArrayOutputStream but I need the output in File or FileInputStream. Is it poossible to convert ByteArrayOutputStream into File?

Comment: If you take a picture with the camera it is mostly in .jpg format. That is already compressed.

Comment: But it is about 2.3 MB and I want it smaller like some KB

Comment: You cannot compress a 2.3 MB .jpg file to some KB. What you can do however is resize the image. But that is something diffferent than compressing.

Comment: For resizing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413659/how-to-resize-image-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is :

```
OutputStream outStream = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutStream = null;
try {  
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myimage.png");
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byteOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byteOutStream.write(bytes);
    byteOutStream.writeTo(outStream);  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} finally {  
    outStream.close();  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296248/how-to-convert-outputstream-to-file
after that is the compressed image in File?

Comment: I updated my answer, see if it works for you, the compressed image should get written to the file.